# Python PANDAS-Substring First INT or FLOAT Before Symbol

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a string column in a PANDAS dataframe I would like substring to create a new column.  The general format for the column is this:

```
"THING 10MG/OTHER THING 100MG"
"THING 10MG"
"THING 10.5MG"
"THING 10.5MCG"
```

What I need is a regex or other pattern matching technique to extract these results:

```
"10"
"10"
"10.5"
"10.5"
```

The result is the first occurrence (from the left) of a float or int before MG or MCG.

What I have so far produces incomplete results obviously:

```
df['string_field'].str.extract('(\d+)MG')
```

Any performant approach or tips would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: `('\d+(\.\d+)?')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need extract `float` or `int` and then if necessary cast to `float`:

```
L = [
"THING 10MG/OTHER THING 100MG",
"7THING 10MG",
"THING 10.5MG",
"THING 10.5MCG"
]

df =pd.DataFrame({'string_field':L})
print (df)
                   string_field
0  THING 10MG/OTHER THING 100MG
1                   7THING 10MG
2                  THING 10.5MG
3                 THING 10.5MCG

print (df['string_field'].str.extract('(\d*\.\d+|\d+)MC?G', expand=False).astype(float))
0    10.0
1    10.0
2    10.5
3    10.5
Name: string_field, dtype: float64
```

Comment: This is perfect.  Particularly with your edit to handle the MC/MCG condition.

Comment: I was wondering if it is not too much trouble what the best way to get the second occurrence would be for this?

Comment: @Pylander not sure if understand, do you need second int or floats? Whats happen if does not exist?

Comment: Thanks @jezrael I ended up finding a workaround for my use case.  Use .str.findall('(\d+)'  to make a series of lists, then extract with .map(lambda x: x[1]).astype(float).  I don't have any missing data luckily so this seems to work OK.

Comment: @Pylander - Yes, it is good code. Very similar should be `str.findall('(\d+').str[1].astype(float)`

Answer (score 2):

A working solution:

```
\b(\d+(\.\d+)?)MC?G
```

`\b` is a word boundary. The `?` means it's optional. This works for both a group or a character.

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/0DQSZ6/1)